# DB2 tables not showing in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, db2

I have connected to a DB2 database in Visual Studio via ODBC (Server Explorer -> Data Connections) 
I can see the database, and I can create queries, but, I cannot see the tables and views. Im quite certain that they were listed earlier on, but they vanished after some upgrade (unfortunately I do not recall what was upgraded.)

Does anyone recognize the problem, and furthermore, does anyone have a solution :)

Regards, Magnus

Answer (score 0):

DB2 Visual Studio integration is all part of the DB2 client installation.  What version of the DB2 client are you using?  Have you tried checking to see if there's a newer client that has a newer version of the Visual Studio add-in?

Look for the Data Server Client (which includes the Visual Studio Add-in) or just the Visual Studio Add-in

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21385217